# How to connect to an existing Kafka MSK Cluster step by step?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I would like to know more about how to connect to a Kafka MSK Cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Kafka client.

Since you have [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), start with [`kafkajs`](https://kafka.js.org/) or [`node-rdkafka`](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka).  I'd recommend `kafkajs` since it supports [SASL consumption with AWS IAM](https://kafka.js.org/docs/1.10.0/configuration#a-name-sasl-a-sasl)

Beyond that, MSK is an implementation detail, and any steps will work for all Kafka clusters (depending on other security implementations). However, cloud providers will require that you allow your client IP address space within the VPC, and you can follow the official [getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) for verifying a basic client will work.